# How to convert response data from rapidapi.com in c# objects

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, rapidapi

I have e response from https://rapidapi.com/ and I retrieve data like that in the web:

```
{1 item
 "data":[1 item
   0:{2 items
   "screen_ID":"76"
   "screen_data":{1 item
   "icoData":{3 items
      "data":[...
      ]3 items
      "tabname":"ongoing"
      "categories":[...
     ]13 items
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

When I try to convert from JSON to C# object from https://json2csharp.com/ I receive:

```
Exception: Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got: i. Path '', line 1, position 3.
```

Is there a way to quick create objects with this data ?

[image: rapidapi]

I need the "data" content.

[image: rapidapi2]

Comment: that is not the actual json - that is a prettified output.  You need to view the raw json - there will be an option for this in your browser or in their UI - and pass that to json2csharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message said that the data you received is not a valid json format. It needs a colon after 1item.

```
{"1 item":{ 
             .....  
           }                     
}
```

Recheck the renponse that you could get the correct json data.